Which rule of deduction should be used?
For one of my previous formal logic quizzes, this was one of the questions.
Study the formal proof below and choose the correct options for steps 2 and 6.
|1. (A ∧ B) ∨ C
+---------------
|    |2. ?
|    +------
|    |3. B            ∧-Elim
|    |4. C ∨ B        ∨-Intro
|
|    |5. C
|    +------
|    |6. C ∨ B        ∨-Intro
|    |7. C ∨ B        Rule?

A. Line 2: Assumption A ∧ B; Line 7: ∨-Elim 1-6
B. Line 2: Assumption A ∨ B; Line 7: ∧-Elim 2-4,5-6
C. Line 2: Assumption A ∧ B; Line 7: ∨-Elim 1,2-4,5-6
D. Line 2: Assumption ¬A ∧ B; Line 7: ∨-Elim 2-4,5-6
The correct answer is supposedly

 C

But this is not obvious to me. The lecturer has inherited the question set from another lecturer and I want to give them the benefit of the doubt but I don't understand their reasoning.
One can maybe narrow down the question to A, C or D maybe because line 2 then makes sense in that case. But the line 7 components for those answers don't make sense to me. 7 looks like a re-iteration of line 6.
What exactly is being eliminated and where? The line references for A and C seem to be saying the same thing.


But the line 7 components for those answers don't make sense to me. 7 looks like a re-iteration of line 6.

That is because line 7 should not be inside the subproof.   It is the concluding sentence for the entire proof.
$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{~~1.~~(A\land B)\lor C}{\fitch{~~2.~~\boxed{\phantom{A\land B}}}{~~3.~~B\hspace{10ex}\land\mathrm E\\~~4.~~B\lor C\hspace{5.75ex}\lor\mathrm I}\\\fitch{~~5.~~C}{~~6.~~B\lor C\hspace{5.5ex}\lor\mathrm I}\\~~7.~~B\lor C\hspace{10ex}\boxed{\textrm{Rule?}}}$$

What exactly is being eliminated and where? The line references for A and C seem to be saying the same thing.

Answer A and C differ by the line references of the inference rule.  One of which is not a valid format.
Answer A references subproof $1{-}6$.
Answer C references line $1$, subproof $2{-}4$, and subproof $5{-}6$.
Now, what form does the rule of disjunction elimination require?

The correct answer is supposedly:

 c


Well, yes, that is the correct answer.

Ironically, the "supposed answer" was my typo -- I have fixed that now. That the lecturer included line 7 in the sub-proof explains why it was so confusing.

@NeRoboto  Well, yes, that is now the correct answer.
